# Align Text with Image within Flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an image and some text below it aligned in a 2x2 Grid using flexbox. Ive used a web of `display: flex;` to get the images and all the required grids to line up. However, I have a problem with the text that appears below the image. I would like the image to appear center in the flexbox and have used `align-items: center` to successfully achieve that. However, I would like the text below the image to align left instead of center like the rest of the flex children. Is that possible the way I have it currently setup?

I have tried to take the text out of the center aligned flexbox div but then it accounts for the text in the parent flexbox and ruins the 2x2 image grid I have created.

Here is the code I have currently (note the snippet squishes everything down so see the CodePen for what actually currently looks like)  and here is a CodePen as well: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vvdaYZ

```css
.header-row {
  background-color: #003F7C;
}

.full-width-eight-normal {
  width: calc(66.6666666667%);
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.full-width-four-normal {
  width: calc(33.3333333333%);
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.meet-outer-div {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-row {
  background-color: #003F7C;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.person-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 40px);
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="meet-outer-div">
  <div class="full-width-eight-normal main-row">
    <div class="person-div">
      <img class="img-resize" src="https://placeimg.com/350/350/animals?random=12">
      <h2 class="white-text">Field Name </h2>
      <h4>Field Position </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="person-div">
      <img class="img-resize" src="https://placeimg.com/350/350/animals?random=12">
      <h2 class="white-text">Field Name </h2>
      <h4>Field Position </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="person-div">
      <img class="img-resize" src="https://placeimg.com/350/350/animals?random=12">
      <h2 class="white-text">Field Name </h2>
      <h4>Field Position </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="person-div">
      <img class="img-resize" src="https://placeimg.com/350/350/animals?random=12">
      <h2 class="white-text">Field Name </h2>
      <h4>Field Position </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="full-width-four-normal numbers-div">
    <ul class="ul-no-bullets">
      <li class="margin-spacing">
        <p id="section-title">This</p>
      </li>
      <li class="margin-spacing">
        <p id="section-title">is Just</p>
      </li>
      <li class="margin-spacing">
        <p id="section-title">Right Side</p>
        <li>
          <p id="section-title">Filler</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've found it's best to avoid using float with flex. instead of `float:right` try `margin-left:auto`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `align-self: start` on the items you want aligned to left:

```css
.header-row {
  background-color: #003F7C;
}

.full-width-eight-normal {
  width: calc(66.6666666667%);
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.full-width-four-normal {
  width: calc(33.3333333333%);
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.meet-outer-div {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-row {
  background-color: #003F7C;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.person-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 40px);
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}
.person-div h2, .person-div h4  {
  align-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="meet-outer-div">
  <div class="full-width-eight-normal main-row">
    <div class="person-div">
      <img class="img-resize" src="https://placeimg.com/350/350/animals?random=12">
      <h2 class="white-text">Field Name </h2>
      <h4>Field Position </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="person-div">
      <img class="img-resize" src="https://placeimg.com/350/350/animals?random=12">
      <h2 class="white-text">Field Name </h2>
      <h4>Field Position </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="person-div">
      <img class="img-resize" src="https://placeimg.com/350/350/animals?random=12">
      <h2 class="white-text">Field Name </h2>
      <h4>Field Position </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="person-div">
      <img class="img-resize" src="https://placeimg.com/350/350/animals?random=12">
      <h2 class="white-text">Field Name </h2>
      <h4>Field Position </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="full-width-four-normal numbers-div">
    <ul class="ul-no-bullets">
      <li class="margin-spacing">
        <p id="section-title">This</p>
      </li>
      <li class="margin-spacing">
        <p id="section-title">is Just</p>
      </li>
      <li class="margin-spacing">
        <p id="section-title">Right Side</p>
        <li>
          <p id="section-title">Filler</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

If you want the text to align with the image, wrap them inside an additional wrapper with `align-items: start`:

```css
.header-row {
  background-color: #003F7C;
}

.full-width-eight-normal {
  width: calc(66.6666666667%);
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.full-width-four-normal {
  width: calc(33.3333333333%);
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.meet-outer-div {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-row {
  background-color: #003F7C;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}

.person-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 40px);
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 10px;
  align-items: center;
}
.person-div div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="meet-outer-div">
  <div class="full-width-eight-normal main-row">
    <div class="person-div">
      <div>
        <img class="img-resize" src="https://placeimg.com/350/350/animals?random=12">
        <h2 class="white-text">Field Name </h2>
        <h4>Field Position </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="person-div">
      <div>
        <img class="img-resize" src="https://placeimg.com/350/350/animals?random=12">
        <h2 class="white-text">Field Name </h2>
        <h4>Field Position </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="person-div">
      <div>
        <img class="img-resize" src="https://placeimg.com/350/350/animals?random=12">
        <h2 class="white-text">Field Name </h2>
        <h4>Field Position </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="person-div">
      <div>
        <img class="img-resize" src="https://placeimg.com/350/350/animals?random=12">
        <h2 class="white-text">Field Name </h2>
        <h4>Field Position </h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="full-width-four-normal numbers-div">
    <ul class="ul-no-bullets">
      <li class="margin-spacing">
        <p id="section-title">This</p>
      </li>
      <li class="margin-spacing">
        <p id="section-title">is Just</p>
      </li>
      <li class="margin-spacing">
        <p id="section-title">Right Side</p>
        <li>
          <p id="section-title">Filler</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add align-self: start for h2 and h4 tag.

```css
.header-row {
  background-color: #003F7C;
}

.person-div h2,
.person-div h4{
align-self:start
}

.full-width-eight-normal {
  width: calc(66.6666666667%);
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.full-width-four-normal {
  width: calc(33.3333333333%);
  float: left;
  margin-left: 0;
}

.meet-outer-div {
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.main-row {
  background-color: #003F7C;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.person-div {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 40px);
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="meet-outer-div">
  <div class="full-width-eight-normal main-row">
    <div class="person-div">
      <img class="img-resize" src="https://placeimg.com/350/350/animals?random=12">
      <h2 class="white-text">Field Name </h2>
      <h4>Field Position </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="person-div">
      <img class="img-resize" src="https://placeimg.com/350/350/animals?random=12">
      <h2 class="white-text">Field Name </h2>
      <h4>Field Position </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="person-div">
      <img class="img-resize" src="https://placeimg.com/350/350/animals?random=12">
      <h2 class="white-text">Field Name </h2>
      <h4>Field Position </h4>
    </div>
    <div class="person-div">
      <img class="img-resize" src="https://placeimg.com/350/350/animals?random=12">
      <h2 class="white-text">Field Name </h2>
      <h4>Field Position </h4>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="full-width-four-normal numbers-div">
    <ul class="ul-no-bullets">
      <li class="margin-spacing">
        <p id="section-title">This</p>
      </li>
      <li class="margin-spacing">
        <p id="section-title">is Just</p>
      </li>
      <li class="margin-spacing">
        <p id="section-title">Right Side</p>
        <li>
          <p id="section-title">Filler</p>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```